# node.js on windows not serving requests to external IP

Tags: windows, node.js, amazon-ec2

I deployed node.js to Amazon EC2 Windows instance. Here is the js code which I run:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80);
```

It works perfectly when I am accessing http://localhost
But it doesn't work when I'm trying to access the server through external IP: http://[external IP]

when I run "netstat -ano" I can see this line:

```
0.0.0.0:80
```

if I run IIS, then it adds two lines

```
0.0.0.0:80
[::]:80
```

What does [::] mean? And why it's not added when I run node.js? I think, that is why node.js isn't serving requests to external IP. How can I make node.js work on Windows?

Comment: That IIS line is for IPv6. Try listen(80, '::'). But maybe it's just that your firewall isn't configured permissive enough.

Comment: Thanks thejh! You answered the question. node.exe was blocked by Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(re-posting comment as answer)

You might have to reconfigure your firewall, it is probably configured too strict.

Comment: Please mention what you need to configure. I also configured my node app in EC2. But it does not respond to the http requests. I checked the firewall, opened port 80, checked instance's security group. nothing seems to be working... Please mention what have you done.

Comment: @user644745 Could you post the fragment of your code where you start the server?

Comment: Finally found the problem.

I introduced log4js and integrated this with express, as,

app.use(log4js.connectLogger(logger, { level: log4js.levels.ERROR }));
This created the problem. Somehow this was failing. Looks like it works only with DEBUG. After commenting this, it started working. Strange !!